# Symfony: any way to show the global errors only if there isn't any field error?

Tags: symfony1

in a form if there is a field and a global error both messages are showed.

I would like to show the global errors only if there isn't any field error.

Any idea?

Comment: if there isn't any field error, how can be a global error?

Comment: for example: i have the signin action of sfDoctrineGuardPlugin. I have empty the 'username' input widget and then click on 'Sign in', this two messages are showed "-Required" and "The username and/or password is invalid". I would like to show just the first message ("-Required").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet should do the job

```
<?php if (0 == ( count($form->getErrorSchema()->getErrors()) - count($form->getErrorSchema()->getGlobalErrors()) ) ):?>
<?php echo $form->renderGlobalErrors()?>
<?php endif?>
```

Comment: Sooooorrry...what works is this:

  <?php 
  
  
   $total_num_errors = count($form->getErrorSchema()->getErrors());
  
   $global_num_errors = count($form->getErrorSchema()->getGlobalErrors());
  
   if (0 == $total_num_errors - $global_num_errors):?>
  
  <?php echo $form->renderGlobalErrors()?>
  <?php endif?>